# Loading content block using AMPScript based on specific date of the year

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We have a journey setup in Marketing Cloud based on a application of a store card. We want to add in a dynamic contact block for holidays indicating processing time will take longer during this period. We need this block to only show between a date range each year as we don't want to update it time and time as people will forget Eg: For Christmas show the block between Dec 20 and Jan 5, year on year and would need the same again for Easter

Is it possible to do this using Ampscript or another recommend method?

Thanks in advance 
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using AMPscript:

```
%%[
var @dateEnd,
    @dateNow,
    @dateStart,
    @nextYear,
    @thisYear

/* all times in UTC; see documentation */
set @dateNow = DateParse(Format(Now(), 'yyyy/MM/dd hh:mmtt'), 1)
set @thisYear = DatePart(@dateNow, 'Y')
set @nextYear = Add(@thisYear, 1)
set @dateStart = DateParse(Concat(@thisYear, '/12/20 00:00AM'), 1)
set @dateEnd = DateParse(Concat(@nextYear, '/01/05 11:59PM'), 1)

if (@dateNow >= @dateStart) and (@dateNow <= @dateEnd) then
]%%
%%=ContentBlockbyId(12345)=%%
%%[
endif
]%%
```

Relevant documentation:

- [DatePart()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/DatePart.htm)
- [DateParse()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/DateParse.htm)
- [Format()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Format.htm)
- [Now()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Now.htm)
- [Date and Time formatting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/dateTimeFormatting.htm)

You'll need to consider timezones and adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can handle this in ampscript using the [datepart()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/DatePart.htm) function.

You get the month and day using this function and then put through a conditional statement.

```
%%[
  Set @month = DatePart(NOW(), 'month')
  Set @day = DatePart(NOW(), 'day')

IF (@month == 12 AND @day > 19) or (@month == 1 AND @day < 6) then

]%%

<h1>We be slow cuz it chritmus</h1>

%%[
ENDIF
]%%
```

Comment: I get the following error, any idea what im doing wrong? Sorry really poor at understanding Ampscript: There is an error in your email. Please contact your customer service representative.
 An unrecognized expression appears in a script block.
 Script Expression: Dartpart
 MemberID: 7242161
 JobID: 0
 <br>Invalid Content: <br>Set @month = Dartpart
There is an error in your email. Please contact your customer service representative.
Same error for day as well just cant paste it in here as run out of room

Comment: @Andyw change `Dartpart` to `DatePart`

Comment: Just to get my understanding right: When you insert AMPScript like this you will not actually change the email that has been received from the customer but change emails that are being send within a certain particular date range, right?

Comment: @JohannesSchapdick - yes, SFMC AMPscript and SSJS can only change at send time. Realtime changes currently can only happen via Image swapping (hosted images that are swapped server side according to conditions) or advanced CSS (which is not well supported currently).

Comment: @Andyw - can you edit your question and put your current code block in there so I can help debug it? As it stands, the AMPscript I put in there works, so it might just be a simple syntax issue caused by the other parts of your email. Also, please make sure to put all AMPscript either in an HTML content block or only inside the HTML tab of all other content blocks. Putting it in as text in the WYSIWYG will usually either cause it act as a string (not processed), or produce unexpected errors or behavior.

Comment: @Gortonington, I have gone back to the basics and created a blank email with no additional AMPScript

`%%[
  Set @month = DatePart(NOW(), 'month')
  Set @day = DatePart(NOW(), 'day')

IF (@month == 3 AND @day > 10) or (@month == 4 AND @day < 6) then

Stuff goes here

ENDIF
]%%`
It doesn't error now however the stuff goes here text does not show
I am created as a HTML block entering the code via the HTML tab

Comment: @Andyw - updated my answer to show how to directly output content inside the conditional

Comment: @Gortonington Thanks for that, working perfect now, such a silly thing for me to miss